# Angular 2 template's element reference not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, error-handling

I am trying to manipulate html p tags text directly from template using angulars reference elements, but getting error

[image]

this is my code

```
<p>
    <span *ngFor="let queuedTask of tasks">
      <pomodoro-task-icons
        [task]="queuedTask"
        (mouseover)="tooltip.innerText = queuedTask.name"
        (mouseout)="tooltip.innerText = 'text'">
      </pomodoro-task-icons>
    </span>
  </p>
  <p *ngIf="queuedPomodoros > 0" #tooltip>{{tooltip.innerText || 'Mouseover for details' }}</p>
```

I am using this code from book and don't find any problem in realization myself.

Comment: Do this {{tooltip | json}} I think your tooltip is null. Make sure to instantiate it.

Comment: I think you are trying to access `#tooltip` which is not exist, you could check first it exist or not then do manipulation over that DOM like `(mouseover)="tooltip && tooltip.innerText = queuedTask.name"`

Comment: Hi bobek, I used json pipe, but it shows nothing, also #tooltip I used assuming that it is reference to p tag and I want to use p tags innerText

Comment: I added #tooltip to p tag
`<p *ngIf="queuedPomodoros > 0" #tooltip>{{tooltip.innerText || 'Mouseover for details' }}</p>`

Comment: what exactly you are trying to achieve? "Manipulate html" is too broad. Also **Angular** is not about manipulation html directly.

Comment: Andrei Zhytkevich, want to change p tags innerText

Comment: If you replace `*ngIf="queuedPomodoros > 0"` with `[hidden]="queuedPomodoros < 1"` it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a `variable` in your component

Reference this `variable` in the `p` tag:

```
 <p *ngIf="queuedPomodoros > 0">{{ variable }}</p>
```

Change the value of the `variable`:

```
  <pomodoro-task-icons
    [task]="queuedTask"
    (mouseover)="variable = queuedTask.name"
    (mouseout)="variable = 'text'">
  </pomodoro-task-icons>
```

Comment: you are just hero **Zhytkevich**